# DropDownList DataSourceID in ListView DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

Why can't I use SelectedValue on my DropDownList !?

I tried `SelectedValue="<% BindItem.current_contact.status_id %>"` but the error says *it is not a valid parameter*. And `Bind("status_id")` does not work either: "*The server tag is not correct.*" on my DropDownList.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SdsStatus"
SelectCommand="SELECT SP.status_id, SP.sp_label, SP.sp_order FROM tr_status SP WHERE SP.groupe_id = @groupe_id ORDER BY SP.sp_order ;                                                                       " ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBLOGIPRO %>">
<SelectParameters>                           
  <ctrl:ClassPropertyParameter Name="groupe_id" ClassName="User" PropertyPath="CurrentNego.groupe_id" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>                                                                  
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="LvContact"
    RenderOuterTable="false"
    SelectMethod="GetAccountWithContacts" ItemType="AccountWithContactsDTO"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateAccountWithContacts">

    <EditItemTemplate>
     ...
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DdlStatus" EnableViewState="true"
        DataSourceID="SdsStatus"
        DataTextField="sp_label" DataValueField="status_id" 
        DataTextFormatString="{0}" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged"                                                                      
        AutoPostBack="true">

          <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>                                   
   </EditItemTemplate>                                        
  </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set the SelectValue in ListView's ItemDataBound event. There you can handle controls' attribute values.
I am not sure if you can handle this kind of attribute with Bind() method directly in aspx.